# Why is a shadow being applied to svg on safari?

Tags: css, svg, safari

Any ideas why this strange shadow effect is being added to my svgs when viewing on safari (mobile)?
[image]

This is how the original looks:
[image]

Comment: Please post the source of the SVG as well as any CSS being applied to it. My guess is that there's a syntax error in your fill that Safari is ignoring but Chrome isn't (or vice versa)

Comment: yes, i shouldve pasted the code html aswel... the answer was there! these buttons had 'type="submit"' applied which webkit added some styling to. sorted now. thanks

Comment: try: `-webkit-appearance:none`